# How to refactor my code to avoid duplicating

Tags: swift, uibutton, uilabel, refactoring, extension-methods

I have a function which modifies the text of UILabel and does something with it.
Do that, I created my function in an UILabel extension.
It's work perfectly

```
extension UILabel {

   let replaced = self.text.doSomething()

   func animate() {

      UIView.transition(with: self, duration: duration,options:[], animations: {
        self.text = replaced
      }

   }    
}
```

I need exactly the same thing, but for the text of UIButton.

Is there a way WITHOUT duplicating the same code in UIButton Extension?

Answer (score 4):

How about making a protocol?

```
protocol AnimationProtocol {}

class SomeUIButton: UIButton, AnimationProtocol {}

class SomeUILabel: UILabel, AnimationProtocol {}

extension AnimationProtocol {

   let replaced = self.text.doSomething()

   func animate() {

      UIView.transition(with: self, duration: duration,options:[], animations: {
        self.text = replaced
      }

   }    
}
```

Comment: Button has a title, label has text. this wont work for button

Comment: Dang, I forgot about that. Could perform a check within the method, like `if self is UIButton {} else {}`

Comment: @BenjaminBreiby I would suggest against hard coding types like that

Answer (score 1):

One possible way of doing it would be to make a protocol and create a common property that can be used across types

```
import UIKit

protocol textSettable: class {
    var textValue: String { get set }

    func doSomething() -> String
    func animate()
}

extension textSettable where Self: UIButton {
    var textValue: String? {
        get {
            return self.titleLabel?.text
        }
        set {
            self.titleLabel?.text = newValue
        }
    }
}

extension textSettable where Self: UILabel {
    var textValue: String? {
        get {
            return self.text
        }
        set {
            self.text = newValue
        }
    }
}

extension textSettable {

    func doSomething() -> String {
        return String(textValue.reversed())
    }

    func animate() {
        UIView.transition(with: self, duration: duration,options:[], animations: {
             self.text = doSomething()
        }
    }
}
```

This way you are 'decorating' the text value for each type you want to work with.

Comment: in  `UIView.transition(with:self` self should be UILabel or UIButton

Comment: add a guard statement to check if self is UILabel or self is UIButton

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the part which concerns how to set the text of label/button: `mylabel.textValue = "test"`? but I have an error `'UILabel' has no member 'textValue'`

Answer (score 1):

The first part is so UILabel and UIButton both have a text attribute.

```
protocol TextProtocol: class {
    var text: String? { get set }
}
extension UIButton: TextProtocol {
    var text: String? {
        get {
            return self.titleLabel?.text
        } set {
            self.titleLabel?.text = newValue
        }
    }
}
extension UILabel: TextProtocol {}
```

The second part builds on the first and makes sure that UILabel and UIButton both have an `animate(text:duration:)` function.

```
protocol AnimatableTextProtocol: TextProtocol where Self: UIView {}
extension AnimatableTextProtocol {
    func animate(text: String, duration: TimeInterval) {
        UIView.transition(with: self, duration: duration, options: [], animations: { 
            self.text = text
            })
    }
}
extension UILabel: AnimatableTextProtocol {}
extension UIButton: AnimatableTextProtocol {}
```

Note: If you leave off the `class`from the TextProtocol, the animate function will see its `self` as immutable because a value type will also be able to inherit from the protocol. With the `class` part the AnimatableTextProtocol knows it works with a reference type which makes `self` mutable and so the text attribute assignable to.

```
func yeah(button: UIButton, label: UILabel) {
    button.text = "hello"
    label.text = "world"

    button.animate(text: "hello2", duration: 0.5)
    label.animate(text: "world", duration: 1.5)
}
```